# regex help: trying to find a email address

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Trying to use Eclipse regex search to find email addresses ( i.e. anything@domain.com) in files where the specific user is not user.a@domain.com or user.b@domain.com.

Using the string below the items in bold need to be found, while the other addresses need to be skipped:
**bob@domain.com**,user.b@domain.com,**andy@domain.com**,user.a@domain.com

I've got as far as the following but its not working as I think it should. 
\b(?!user.b)\w*@domain.com\b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?!user\.b@domain.com|user\.a@domain.com).*[\w]+[\w]?[\w./]+@[\w_]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\.?[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
```

This will find all email addresses regardless of domain, just keep appending to list of not 
`user\.b@domain.com|user\.a@domain.com|` more email addresses and escape the `"."`

Comment: This only works if each email address is on a single line with no whitespace.  Furthermore, you can't simply remove the `^` and `$` anchors to rectify that, because that breaks the regex.  It will then match user.a@domain.com, along with whatever is before it.

Comment: You also failed to escape the `.` metacharacter in your negative matching.  Thus you will also incorrectly fail to match `user1a@domain.com`.

Comment: thats correct, but they can be added it ^(?!user\.b@domain.com|user\.a@domain.com).*[\w]+[\w]?[\w./]+@[\w_]+.[a-zA-Z]+.?[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$  done, however yes its one item per line, I was suspecting someone to manually look at each line found, as it was an eclipse search, not thinking it was for searching strings of emails addresses

Comment: actually when I click to edit it shows, the negation in the ignore email addresses, so not sure why they show here, first time I've entered anything on stackoverflow sorry

Comment: looks like stackoverflow removes any instance of "\." from my code and replaces it with "." is there a way to tell it not to?

Comment: Edit your answer and format your regex as 'code' in the editor. Then the escape backslash will show up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your exact requirements, but this will match anything not of the form user.[letters and numbers]@domain.com (and not containing `.` on the left side).

```
(?<!user\.)\w+@domain\.com\b
```

Your original had a couple of problems:

- . is a word boundary, so you would match "a@domain.com" out of "user.a@domain.com".
- `.` within a regex is a metacharacter, so you have to escape it.
- You needed to use a look-behind assertion rather than the simple `(?! ... )` construct.

Update: [here is the Perl regex documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).  Eclipse follows this, generally speaking.

**Further update:** just to clarify, my code would not match any email addresses that contain dots left of the @.  If you need to match other addresses with dots, it actually starts to get quite complicated due to the nature of lookbehind.  This modified version would match addresses with anything but user. followed by 1 to 5 characters.

```
[\w\.]+(?<!user\.\w{1,5})@domain\.com\b
```

Comment: This works badly if there is a nonword character in the address http://rubular.com/r/mn12f7Iqcu

Comment: @Gabber, the second one fixes that for dot characters.  It doesn't work in Ruby (your link), but it works in Eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

Actually it's discouraged to check email addresses with regex, the best you can do is sending a confirmation email. I agree, it's not always possible, but that's the most reliable way you can have.

See details in http://davidcelis.com/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/ and the accompanying reddit discussion http://de.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/zgumq/stop_validating_email_addresses_with_regex/

Comment: Being in eclipse I think we are talking of source code... **Would you really send confirmation emails to any email addresses found in a source file to check for existence?????????????????????**

Comment: As I wrote: _I agree, it's not always possible, but that's the most reliable way you can have._ But the email specification is so vague, that you'll have a hard time to cover all corner cases. If you have a naming scheme for the email addresses that you can encounter (e.g. inside the company everyone gets a `firstname.lastname@company.com` type of email with only letters in their names), then you can do it. But not in a general case. Some tricky situations: the domain name can be an IPv6 address, you can use character escaping before the '@' to basically have any kind of characters there, etc.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain well..
1- he is not trying to validate email addresses, he is just trying to *find* something looking like an email address in his text. 
2- email address format is a standard (RFC822 if I'm not wrong) and it is possible to write at least a finite state machine to validate it. Moreover some providers handle this standard in a wrong manner telling users that standard-valid addresses are not valid, making the "send a test mail" test non working.

Comment: No worries, I have also realized that I tried to solve (or not solve) a more general problem. The RFC is actually *2*822, but that's just a typo. ;) If you have some free time during the weekend, I encourage you to read through those two links in my answer. It's way too much effort to write a fully RFC-compliant regex to match email addresses. It's similar to the "match HTML with regex" story: for simple cases you can do it, but thing will become overly complicated pretty soon. (Yeah, I know, with HTML the problem comes from it not being a _regular_ language, but you get the idea.)

Comment: I don't agree with this.  The specification may let you have `!{}"??@foo.com`, but in practice no one does that.  Parsing an email address with a regex is almost never going to be a problem.  This is quite unlike the situation with HTML, where *real-world code* will almost always break a regex.

Comment: @dan1111, have you considered non-latin characters? IPv6 addresses as domain names (e.g. `@gmail.com` can be written as `@2a00:1450:8005::53` too)? It gets ugly pretty quickly... I'm from Hungary, and we have non-latin characters, and some people _do_ include those in their email address.

Comment: @battery, yeah, I have to admit that you have a point with that.  I agree that there are some dangers and issues to be aware of.  But I don't agree with the "never do it" conclusion of the post you linked to.

Comment: @dan1111, I agree, _"never do it"_ is too extreme. That's why I wrote _"it's discouraged"_. The "redditers" at the other link also come to the conclusion, that do something simple based on your user base, and don't even try to write a perfect "oraculum" for matching emails. But the real point is, I have answered a question nobody asked. :D